# Mapbox-gl line layer from source as fill layer

Tags: javascript, html, web, mapbox-gl

### Mapbox GL JS w/ w3w grid

Hi, I'm just playing around with the What3Words grid on Mapbox code from the tutorial. (https://developer.what3words.com/tutorial/displaying-the-what3words-grid-on-a-mapbox-map)

I'm trying to make the tiles from the grid interactive, kind of like in the w3w website (clickable, hover effect, getting data from them, etc), but the grid doesn't seem to work when the data source is loaded as a 'fill' layer on Mapbox, it only works as a 'line' layer type. Every single example I find online uses Polygons (or MultiPolygons) from a fill layer type, but I can't see nothing around with bounding boxes.
(Basically trying to achieve something like this, but with every tile instead of the states: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/hover-styles/)

I don't really know what's going on, why can't I add the source data as a fill layer? Is there a way to load the data as Polygons instead of bounding boxes?

Thanks.

Code (from the tutorial):

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://assets.what3words.com/sdk/v3.1/what3words.js?key=YOUR_API_KEY"></script>
    <script src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.53.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>

    <link href="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.53.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style>
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }

      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      // Create the Mapbox
      mapboxgl.accessToken = "YOUR_MAPBOX_TOKEN";
      let map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: "map", // container id
        style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9", // stylesheet location
        center: [-0.195499, 51.52086], // starting position [lng, lat]
        zoom: 18 // starting zoom
      });
      map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());
    </script>
    <script>
      function drawGrid() {
        const zoom = map.getZoom();
        const loadFeatures = zoom > 17;

        if (loadFeatures) { // Zoom level is high enough
          var ne = map.getBounds().getNorthEast();
          var sw = map.getBounds().getSouthWest();

          // Call the what3words Grid API to obtain the grid squares within the current visble bounding box
          what3words.api
            .gridSectionGeoJson({
              southwest: {
                lat: sw.lat, lng: sw.lng
              },
              northeast: {
                lat: ne.lat, lng: ne.lng
              }
            }).then(function(data) {
              // Get the grid source from the map (it won't exist initally)
              var grid = map.getSource('grid');

              if (grid === undefined) {
                // Create a source of type 'geojson' which loads the GeoJSON returned from the what3words API
                map.addSource('grid', {
                  type: 'geojson',
                  data: data
                });

                // Create a new layer, which loads data from the newly created data source
                map.addLayer({
                  id: 'grid_layer',
                  type: "line",
                  source: 'grid',
                  layout: {
                    "line-join": "round",
                    "line-cap": "round"
                  },
                  paint: {
                    "line-color": '#777',
                    "line-width": .5
                  }
                });
              } else {
                // The source and map layer already exist, so just update the source data to be the new
                // GeoJSON returned from the what3words API
                map.getSource('grid').setData(data);
              }
            }).catch(console.error);
        }

        // If we have reached the required zoom level, set the 'grid_layer' to be visible
        var grid_layer = map.getLayer('grid_layer');
        if (typeof grid_layer !== 'undefined') {
          map.setLayoutProperty('grid_layer', 'visibility', loadFeatures ? 'visible' : 'none');
        }
      }

      // When the map is either loaded or moved, check to see if the grid should be draw
      // if the appropriate zoom level has been met, and if so draw it on.
      map
        .on('load', drawGrid)
        .on('move', drawGrid);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```